# Last 30 days and % of weighted average Sales- Trailing date Range

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I'm trying to build a calculated True/False field. I'm struggling with creating a trailing date range to make the formula just evaluate the last 30 days.

I want to create a formula that displays:

IF in the last 30 days SUM([rev]) > 500 AND SUM([QTY]) > 10 AND the current listing price for a unit of the material is less than 70% of the last 30 day [AvgWeightedPrice] 
THEN "True"
ELSE "False"
END

I am using a standard [Date] field (mm/dd/yyyy)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(SUM([rev in the last 30 days]) > 500,IF(SUM([QTY]) > 10,IF([the current listing price for a unit of the material] < (.7 * [AvgWeightedPrice]), "True", "False"), "False"),"False")`

That's your IF formula, but without seeing values or ranges or anything except a description I can't help you out more. You're going to have to enter the ranges/value for anything in brackets yourself.